# Vapor swift Code working on localhost but after deploying at heroku all apis working fine but this one crashes

Tags: swift, api, backend, vapor

This function is called when api hits, Looks like error is in return statement in second do block, it is working good on local host but after deploying on heroku and hitting this api, it says
***Could not cast value of type 'Vapor.Request' (0x55e629265b00) to 'Swift.Error' (0x7fd61a06b560).***

[image]

I faced same error once in localhost and using ***try*** fixed that.

```
func updateInterestInJob(_ req: Request) throws -> Future<SeekerInterestInJob> {
    
    var myInterest = SeekerInterestInJob(userId: 0, annotationId: 0, interest: false, status: 0)
    let decoder = JSONDecoder()
    
    guard let data = req.http.body.data else {
        throw req as! Error
    }
    
    do {
        
        myInterest  = try decoder.decode(SeekerInterestInJob.self, from: data)
        print("Testing print")
        
        do {
            return try SeekerInterestInJob.query(on: req).filter(\SeekerInterestInJob.userId, .equal,myInterest.userId).filter(\SeekerInterestInJob.providerId, .equal,myInterest.providerId).filter(\SeekerInterestInJob.annotationId, .equal,myInterest.annotationId).first().flatMap { (foundInterest) -> EventLoopFuture<SeekerInterestInJob> in

                if foundInterest == nil {
                    print("interest not found")
                    return myInterest.save(on: req)
                }
                else {
                    print("interest found")
                    foundInterest?.userId = myInterest.userId
                    foundInterest?.providerId = myInterest.providerId
                    foundInterest?.annotationId = myInterest.annotationId

                    if myInterest.status != 0 {
                        foundInterest?.status = myInterest.status
                        foundInterest?.interest = foundInterest?.interest
                    }
                    else {
                        foundInterest?.interest = myInterest.interest
                    }

                    return (foundInterest?.update(on: req))!
                }
            }
        }
        catch {
            print("in inner catch block")
            return myInterest.update(on: req)
        }
    }
    catch {
        print("in outer catch block")
        return myInterest.update(on: req)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, your issue is right here, at the top of your method:

```swift
guard let data = req.http.body.data else {
    throw req as! Error
}
```

Vapor's `Request` type doesn't conform to the `Error` protocol, so this typecast will crash 100% percent of the time. Instead, you should be using Vapor's built-in `Abort` error type, which can be used to represent any HTTP error.

```swift
guard let data = req.http.body.data else {
    throw Abort(.badRequest, reason: "Missing request body")
}
```

Comment: Can you please explain a little to clear my concept that why it is working on localhost if "throw req as! Error" is wrong and request type does't confirm to error protocol.

Comment: It probably worked locally because the request you sent had a body, which would allow the `guard` statement to succeed and not reach the failure clause.